# feynman diagram with two loops and bigger dots tikz feynman

Tags: diagrams, feynman, tikz-feynman

I am trying to draw Feynman diagrams with two loops. I have managed to draw the following one:

```
\documentclass[DIV=14,headsepline]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\[
    \feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, layered layout]{
    a[dot]  -- c [dot] --[out=135, in=45, loop, min distance=2cm,insertion=0.5] c -- b [dot],
    };
\]
\end{document}
```

Which gives me,

[image]

I would like to add another loop just above the first one but I don't know how. I have tried using `tikzpicture` but I haven't arrived to any result.

Another problem I have is that I would like some dots to be bigger in order to have source terms (big dots) and vertices (small dots) but I don't know how to do it either. `[big=dot]` is not working.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code snippet compilable by adding the documentclass, the required packages and the document environment.

Comment: I use scrartcl for document class and luainputenc because tikz-feyman works on Lualatex. I use the version `\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that tikz-feynman implements the "insertion" option using a decoration instead of a new node. It's therefore tricky to find the position of the vertex at the top of the loop in order to draw a second loop above the first.

A good workaround is to use relative node positions:

```
\documentclass[DIV=14,headsepline]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\[
  \feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b]{
    a[dot]  -- c [dot] -- b [dot],

    c --[out=135, in=185, min distance=0.6cm] d[dot, above = 2cm of c]
      --[out=355, in=45, min distance=0.6cm] c,

    d --[out=135, in=185, min distance=0.6cm]
      e[large, dot, above = 4cm of c]
      --[out=355, in=45, min distance=0.6cm] d,

    e --[out=135, in=185, min distance=0.6cm]
      f[small, blob, above = 6cm of c]
      --[out=355, in=45, min distance=0.6cm] e,
  };
\]
\end{document}
```

This yields the following diagram when compiled with LuaLaTeX:
[image: Feynman diagram with several loops]

I've also changed the styles of two of the vertices to show you some of the options that are available.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
\begin{feynman}
\vertex(in);
\tikzfeynmanset{every vertex={dot,minimum size=4mm}} %<- change the size of the dots here
\vertex[right=1.5cm of in] (v);
\vertex[above=1.2cm of v] (u);
\tikzfeynmanset{every vertex={empty dot,minimum size=0mm}} %<- ugly, I know
\vertex[right=1.5cm of v] (out);
\vertex[above=1.2cm of u] (w);
\diagram{(in)  -- (v) -- (out)};
\diagram{(v)  -- [half left] (u) -- [half right] (w) -- [half right] (u) -- [half left] (v)};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I compiled with xelatex (since I am not able to get lualatex working) and that this is my very first diagram drawn with tikz-feynman, so undoubtedly there is a lot of room for improvement.

**EDIT**: This is an attempt to make the diagram a bit more appealing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
\begin{feynman}
\vertex(in);
\vertex[right=1.5cm of in] (v);
\vertex[above=1.2cm of v] (u);
\vertex[right=1.5cm of v] (out);
\vertex[above=1.2cm of u] (w);
\diagram{(in)  -- (v) -- (out)};
\diagram{(v)  -- [half left] (u) -- [half right] (w) -- [half right] (u) -- [half left] (v)};
\draw[fill=black] (v) circle(1.5mm);
\draw[fill=black] (u) circle(1.5mm);
% \draw (1.5,0.6) circle (0.6cm); %<- uncomment this line to compare the loop toa real circle
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! something like this is what I am looking for. (I wish I could draw something as good as this in my first attempt)

Comment: Thanks to both that tried to answer! I worked out a solution now ^^